# ValueError: Shape of passed values is (20, 1), indices imply (20, 6)

Tags: python, pandas, list, dataframe

I am trying to get data from tif files, store it in `data` and create a pandas `df0`

```
data = []
listOfPages = glob.glob(r"C:/Users/name/*.tif")
for entry in listOfPages:
    text = pytesseract.image_to_string(
            Image.open(entry), lang="en"
        )
    data.append(text)
    
    duck1 = re.compile(r'(CHE)(.*)\\n', flags = re.DOTALL | re.MULTILINE)
    asker1 = re.compile(r'(my|the)\s+zzzz(.*)office', flags = re.DOTALL | re.MULTILINE)
    date1 = re.compile(r'\s+dfg(\d{2}\.\d{2}\.\d{4})', flags = re.DOTALL | re.MULTILINE)
    th1 = re.compile(r'(gh|gh)\s+fg\s+sdf(.*)(rrr,\s+rtr)', flags = re.DOTALL | re.MULTILINE)
    frage1 = re.compile(r'(\\neee)(.*)(we|wzz)\s+drte\s+Srrr:', flags = re.DOTALL | re.MULTILINE)
    try:
        d2 = duck1.search(text)
        if d2:
            dru = d2.group(1)
        else:
            dru = None
    except:
        pass
    try:
        asker2 = asker1.search(text)
        if asker2:
            asker = asker2.group(1)
        else:
            asker = None
    except:
        pass
    try:
        date2 = date1.search(text)
        if date2:
            datr = date2.group(0)
        else:
            datr = None
    except:
        pass
    try:
        thema2 = thema1.search(text)
        if thema2:
            thema = thema2.group(1)
        else:
            thema = None
    except:
        pass
    try:
        frage2 = frage1.search(text)
        if frage2:
            frage = frage2.group(1)
        else:
            frage = None
    except:
        pass
    data.append([text, dru, asker, datr, thema, frage])
    
df0 = pd.DataFrame(data, columns =['raw_text', 'wer', 'asker', 'date', 'area', 'que_text'])
print(df0)
```

**ValueError: Shape of passed values is (20, 1), indices imply (20, 6)**

What am i doing wrong? I understand the error (from reading on the same subject but different scenarios) that there is supposed to be overlapping indices i would need to drop before appending?

Comment: You are passing `data` which is of shape (20,1) while your dataframe needs something of shape (20,6). This is happening most probably because your all six values are contained in a single list.

Comment: Your `data` is like this `[text, list, text, list, text, list, ...]`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just have to stop appending `text` initially to `data` as you are doing it at the last of the loop in the list and this creates `data` as a list of lists with shape(20,6) which you need.

```
for entry in listOfPages:
    text = pytesseract.image_to_string(
            Image.open(entry), lang="en"
        )
    #data.append(text)
    
    duck1 = re.compile(r'(CHE)(.*)\\n', flags = re.DOTALL | re.MULTILINE)
    asker1 = re.compile(r'(my|the)\s+zzzz(.*)office', flags = re.DOTALL | re.MULTILINE)
    date1 = re.compile(r'\s+dfg(\d{2}\.\d{2}\.\d{4})', flags = re.DOTALL | re.MULTILINE)
    th1 = re.compile(r'(gh|gh)\s+fg\s+sdf(.*)(rrr,\s+rtr)', flags = re.DOTALL | re.MULTILINE)
    frage1 = re.compile(r'(\\neee)(.*)(we|wzz)\s+drte\s+Srrr:', flags = re.DOTALL | re.MULTILINE)
    try:
        d2 = duck1.search(text)
        if d2:
            dru = d2.group(1)
        else:
            dru = None
    except:
        pass
    try:
        asker2 = asker1.search(text)
        if asker2:
            asker = asker2.group(1)
        else:
            asker = None
    except:
        pass
    try:
        date2 = date1.search(text)
        if date2:
            datr = date2.group(0)
        else:
            datr = None
    except:
        pass
    try:
        thema2 = thema1.search(text)
        if thema2:
            thema = thema2.group(1)
        else:
            thema = None
    except:
        pass
    try:
        frage2 = frage1.search(text)
        if frage2:
            frage = frage2.group(1)
        else:
            frage = None
    except:
        pass
    data.append([text, dru, asker, datr, thema, frage])
    
df0 = pd.DataFrame(data, columns =['raw_text', 'wer', 'asker', 'date', 'area', 'que_text'])
print(df0)
```

This should work fine.